# Facebook custom HTML page not working in Chrome

Tags: html, facebook, google-chrome, iframe

I have created custom HTML facebook page by pasting my own source code. Its working fine in all browsers Firefox, Safari, IE. But in Google Chrome its not loading external CSS, javascript and everything. Its just text.

Facebook page here:
http://www.facebook.com/KoucPavelMilanCerny/app_190322544333196

Any ideas what to do? Is Chrome blocking loading of external CSS in iframes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the Chrome Inspector tool and look in the console tab you see these issues:
[image]

Try hosting your css and js on the same server as the web page.

Comment: Thank you for this tip but how can I host CSS and js on the same server as web page? Web page is hosted on facebook.